# AdMob: background requests?

Tags: android, background, admob

I am monitoring every 20 minutes my AdMob account (user AdMob API).
It appears that there is (roughly speaking) the same number of ad requests every day. But my app is business oriented and mostly used on week days. Connections to the "business" server drops on week-ends by 80%.

So, I am wondering if the AdMob manager isn't sending requests even if the app (Android) is in background mode. By background mode I mean when the user press "Home" or "Back" button on his Android phone and then gets back to the "desktop".

I haven't find any information on background mode and AdMob integration (what we should do in such case).

Have you ever noticed such behavior? Do you know if (and how) the app needs to disable AdMob when going to background mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in LogCat when AdMob is requesting ad. Are you seeing any requests when your app is in the foreground (you should), and when your app pauses (you should not see any requests)?