# Does Admob performs requests when the app is in background?

Tags: android, admob

I've integrated AdMob with my app. I can't seem to find this in any AdMob references.

Are AdMobs still running and bringing you revenue even if the app is in background or the ad is not visible? (for example

1. the user pressed the "Home" button
2. the user turned off the screen
3. the ad is positioned outside screen bounds

In my opinon this is clearly a wrong behavior if AdMob is still requesting ads and paying money per impressions in any of the above cases.

How does this actually work? Can anyone point me to a link/reference that exaplains this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking back, home, or closing your phone will pause your application but not terminate it. It is possible to run your application as a Service\WakeLock and it will continue to run in the background. Admob requests should not be running in the background if your application is paused. You should not be receiving impressions or revenue while your application is in the background.

Quote from [AdMob: background requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234051/admob-background-requests?rq=1)

> You can see in LogCat when AdMob is requesting ad. Are you seeing any
> requests when your app is in the foreground (you should), and when
> your app pauses (you should not see any requests)?
>
> By: Android Dev Guy